# Let's update some links

Tags: bug, status-completed, close-reasons

Under **Closing → Off-Topic**, please update:

1. `http` to `https`.
2. `meta.english` to `english.meta`.

for ELU.

Meta ELU's looks okay.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good catch. I have updated the two close reasons that needed it.

As it's a Friday night and it takes two moderators to change a close reason, it may be a few hours before the updates go "live".

Comment: This reminds me to check those links in the site I moderate.