# Two identical close reasons?

Tags: discussion, design

[Wont - contraction or not?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/381972/50044)

[image: image of same close reason, twice]

This is closed with "please include the research...", but the reason shows up twice. What caused it?

Very trivial matter; curious nonetheless.

Comment: It looks like a bug. I'm still researching it though.

Comment: @tchrist Eureka, I guess. I now notice that one of them has https over http for the ELL link.

Comment: How can you tell that?? Oh wait, I see now. How bizarre!

Comment: @tchrist And other links have slight changes as well. I think it might have something to do with [this](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10447/50044) and [that](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10522/50044). Does it help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between those is that the first one with three names mentions ELL using an HTTP link, and the second one with two names mentions ELL with an HTTPS link. So they aren't quite the same.

I <s>suspect a bot</s> see that MetaEd♦ went around fixing these soon after Jul 7 '17 at 22:40, although I'm not sure when those were approved.

In any case, the text changed between Jul 5 '17 at 19:40 when the last HTTP-mentioning close-vote was cast and Jul 8 '17 at 16:05 when the first HTTPS-mentioning close-vote was cast.

---

In a comment on [this Meta Stack Exchange post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/295054/153355), an SE staff member remarks:

> Ugh, yeah. Pretty much all the custom off-topic reasons are going to be HTTP links because they were likely written that way when they were created on-site (those aren't generated by the system but are just saved Markdown). They'll all have to be edited by devs (not recreated by moderators, so that the changes will retroactively apply to older posts previously closed with those reasons). – animuson♦ Apr 22 '17 at 16:20

I’ve pinged him asking whether this is (really?) worth bugging a dev into editing for us.

Comment: I wish life problems could be solved this quickly. :) And, in a way, glad to have completed a trilogy on close reason design bug questions.

Comment: Yeah, MetaEd "fixed" the close reason, but the old one will have to be [edited by devs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295054/links-in-close-reasons-are-sometimes-still-http#comment957084_295054) so that   the change applies to all posts closed with that reason while it was still HTTP.